# Undefined variable

Tags: php, mysql, undefined

I have this code right here:

```
 $conn = db_connect();
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $result = $conn->query("select * from where username='".$username"'");
    if (!$result) throw new Exception ("Could not excecute query");
    }
```

The error message that I'm having troubles with is saying there's an undefined variable in one of these lines. It's only saying this for the `$result = $conn->query("select * from where username='".$username"'");` line even though everything seems to be defined. If anyone knows how to fix this error, please let me know!

Comment: What is the **EXACT** message.

Comment: What if you `echo $username` before the `$result =` line? Do you get anything?

Comment: This is the exact message: Notice: Undefined variable: act in C:\Users\koenigmh\Documents\website1\signupform.php

Comment: @Max: there is no variable `act` in this code. You're looking to a wrong file. Look at the message once again - it points you to a file and a corresponding line

Comment: What type of object is `$conn`?

Comment: @Max where is your table defined in your query?

Comment: $conn connects to the database

Comment: @Max I can guess *what* it does. I wanted to know what type of object it is. What is its class?

Comment: 1. Syntax php error 2. Syntax sql error 3. notice about undefined variable from another file. This question is amazing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the code to this:

```
 $conn = db_connect();
$username = $_POST['username'];
$result = $conn->query("select * from table_name where username='".$username."'");
if (!$result) throw new Exception ("Could not excecute query");
}
```

You forgot the ending period after the username. As one of the comments above noted. You also need to specify a table name so you'll need to replace table_name with your table name.

Comment: Even better would be to use a prepared statement with a bound parameter. No string concatenation required and also avoids SQL injection